# Single NuGet Package Containing x86 ARM x64 binaries

Tags: x86, windows-runtime, nuget, windows-phone

Is there any way of making a single NuGet package that contains binaries targeting x86 ARM x64 etc. so that VisStudio/MSBuild will pick up the correct binaries for each given build configuration?

I can only see support for os target - i.e.
Windows, Windows8, win, win8, wp, wp7, WindowsPhone, WindowsPhone7, silverilght4-wp71, wp71, WindowsPhone71 etc.

And you end up with a folder structure like this:

```
\content
    \net11
    \MyContent.txt
    \net20
        \MyContent20.txt
    \net40
    \sl40
        \MySilverlightContent.html

\tools
    init.ps1
    \net40
        install.ps1
        uninstall.ps1
    \sl40
        install.ps1
        uninstall.ps1
```

Do I really have to do some powershell-script or pre-build step to accomplish this? It seems like this should be supported by NuGet out-of-the-box?

If I do have to use a script - does anyone have good example code? A ps1 script or some sort of build hook?

I also found this work item on the subject: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/679. But its been around since June 2011, last commented in July.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Jon

Sources:

- http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1
- http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Framework_Names

Comment: Just found this link too: http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/354463

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this is still unsupported.

This SO question has two answers that should work for you, one for addressing this with a single package, the other a simple multipackage solution:

[How should I create or upload a 32-bit and 64-bit NuGet package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7769580/1636560)

Comment: I think this is still the case according to this issue: [Add 1st class support for assembly platform (x86, x64, ARM, Any CPU)](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/679) which is still "Proposed"

Comment: Apparently this is *still* unsupported. Vote for it at http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/679