# How to Install nuget package in visual studio with 32 bit or 64 bit specific

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

How to Install nuget package in visual studio with 32 bit or 64 bit specific

I have solution where two projects and every project configuration manager in both directing to x64 only , and we removed x86 from options totally from each project configuration manager

while trying to

install - package of DB2.dll ,

its downloading both x64 and x86 folders in packages folder but in
 Refernce -> properties - > Path  its taking x86 dll ,
 where it should direct to the x64 folder/dll

any command to specify to only install the 64 bit

Comment: Can't you just change the reference to point at the x64 dll?

Comment: @shaswatatripathy, what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> any command to specify to only install the 64 bit

Apparently specific target for 32 or 64 bit architectures is **still unsupported**. You can vote it at: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/679

This question has two answers, you can check them. One is address this with a single package by following [System.Data.SQLite.org](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) to implement Native Library Pre-loading.

The other is to use multi-package. Create two DB2 packages, One for x86 and the other for x64, add DB2`s x64 package to your project.

[How to deal with x86 vs x64 packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446374/how-to-deal-with-x86-vs-x64-packages)