# How to use nuget runtimes to target different CPU architectures in the same package?

Tags: .net, nuget, win-universal-app

I'm trying to create a nuget package for UWP targeting separate CPU architecture builds (arm, x64, x86). I'm using nuget 3.3.0. Reading latest [nuget documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/Create/uwp-create), I understood that this can be achieved using "runtimes" folders.

This is package structure:
[image: package structure]

Installing the package to a UWP project adds the dependencies but it doesn't add references for assemblies from lib folders as a result I can't use the content. There are no errors packing or installing the package.

Searching on internet I found other ways to pack CPU architecture specific builds (most relevant ones: [1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/09/02/packaging-a-windows-store-apps-component-with-nuget-part-2.aspx), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769580/how-should-i-create-or-upload-a-32-bit-and-64-bit-nuget-package)). All of them seems to target old nuget versions (<3.0.0).

Are "runtimes" the right way to solve this problem with latest nuget version? If yes what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1221.

In summary, you'll have to place your architecture specific binaries in the `runtimes` folder. 
In addition you need a surface area implementation to be placed in the `ref` folder. 
The trick is to use the `corflags` command to generate the library for your `ref` folder.