# How to pack an x86 / x64 specific C++/CLI DLL with Nuget?

Tags: nuget

I have a C++/CLI DLL that interfaces a third party native DLL. I want to pack this as Nuget.

I followed [this official MS guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks), [this blog post](https://msicc.net/how-to-create-a-multi-architecture-nuget-package-from-a-uwp-class-library/) and [read through this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491904/how-to-use-nuget-runtimes-to-target-different-cpu-architectures-in-the-same-pack).

So here is what I did:

First, I created the proper nuspec file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>CPlusPlusNativeIFace</id>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <title>CPlusPlusNativeIFace</title>
    <authors>Jens Rabe</authors>
    <owners>Who owns that</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>A DLL that makes a native third-party DLL available to .net</description>
    <releaseNotes>foo</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>errm...</copyright>
    <tags>foo bar</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\Release\**" target="runtimes/win-x86/lib/net461" />
    <file src="..\x64\Release\**" target="runtimes/win-x64/lib/net461" />
    <file src="DummyAny\**" target="ref\net461" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Then I compiled the DLL for Release x86 and Release X64. Then I created the `DummyAny` folder, copied the contents of the x86 one in, and used the `corflags` utility like in Links 2 and 3 to strip the 32 bit flag.

When I now `nuget pack` and `nuget add`, and try to reference that package in another project, I always get:

```
Could not install package 'CPlusPlusNativeIFace 1.0.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I double checked that the files are right:

- I have the x86 stuff in `runtimes/win-x86/lib/net461`
- I have the x64 stuff in `runtimes/win-x64/lib/net461`
- I have a `ref/net461` folder with the manipulated dll in

But I still can't load the package.

I also tried putting the CPU specific DLLs into `runtimes/win-x86/native` and `runtimes/win-x64/native` to no avail.

What else am I missing? Does that not work for C++/CLI projects built against .net Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out that the official MS documentation was not usable here.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179461/adding-x86-and-x64-libraries-to-nuget-package?rq=1) was/is listed as "related" here and the accepted answer there made it work for me. I used [the example project on Github](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Nugetx86x64) as a reference.

So here is how I got it to work:

1. Opened the project properties, went to *Configuration Properties / General*, selected *All Configurations* and *All Platforms*, and as *Output Directory*, I specified: `$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`
2. Rebuilt the project for x86 and x64 in Release mode
3. Adapted the Nuspec to be like this:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <package >
   <metadata>
   <id>CPlusPlusNativeIFace</id>
   <version>1.0.5</version>
   <title>Third Party Proxy</title>
   <authors>Jens Rabe</authors>
   <owners>foo</owners>
   <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
   <description>bar</description>
   <releaseNotes>Further experimenting with nuget</releaseNotes>
   <copyright>baz moo</copyright>
   <tags>quux bletch</tags>
   </metadata>
   <files>
   <file src="bin\Win32\Release\**" target="build\x86" />
   <file src="bin\x64\Release\**" target="build\x64" />
   <file src="bin\Win32\Release\**" target="lib\net461" />
   <file src="CPlusPlusNativeIFace.props" target="build\net461" />
   </files>
   </package>
   ```
4. Added a `CPlusPlusNativeIFace.props` which contains the following:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="CPlusPlusNativeIFace" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
     <HintPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\x86\CPlusPlusNativeIFace.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   <Reference Include="CPlusPlusNativeIFace" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
     <HintPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\x64\CPlusPlusNativeIFace.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
   ```

Now I can do `nuget pack CPlusPlusNativeIFace.nuspec` and I get a Nuget package that installs correctly.