# Import nuget package 32 bit or 64 bit based on application

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, nuget

I write an application in C#. 
I build it both as 64 bit and as 32 bit. 
I do not know what happens with the dependencies though through the nuget repository. I would like to have the 32-bit nuget dependencies when building the application as 32 bit and x64 bit dependencies when I build the application as 64.

Is this possible? How can one import architecture dependent nuget package?

Comment: What specific dependency are you trying to import that you are having issues with?

Comment: I haven't run into any issue yet. But I wanted to know how I could do the above before I run into issues. That's the reason I ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I create or upload a 32-bit and 64-bit NuGet package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769580/how-should-i-create-or-upload-a-32-bit-and-64-bit-nuget-package)